# Locally Developing a wordpress website, cant get images to display?

Tags: images, localhost

I'm currently trying to make a website on WordPress locally using XAMPP, I have started a website but i can't make the images display like i do when developing on a host (this is my first local WP development)

Normally, inside `wp-content` i make a folder called `imgs` and then in my code i just use

```
src="/wp-content/imgs/whatever.png"
```

but this isn't working. When i inspect the element in google chrome the folder doesn't even exist. I've tried looking at the permalinks, as well as some `.htaccess` stuff but to no avail. Any help to get my images working would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a relative path like `/some/path/here.jpg`, and you are on `www.example.com`, the browser will look for

```
www.example.com/some/path/here.jpg
```

Which doesn't exist. But you might have noticed that you can use relative path in a CSS file. That's because the path is calculated based on the location of the CSS file, while in your case the images are being calculated based on the location of the current URL.

The main CSS file of your theme is located at `your-theme/style.css`. You can build relative paths within your stylesheet, for example you can use `../imgs/whatever.jpg` in your CSS file to point to `wp-content/imgs/whatever.jpg`. However, storing any file outside upload directory or theme's is not recommended.

What you can do, is to use core functions to create a full dynamic path. For example `get_template_directory_uri();` will get the current theme's path, so you can use in your image's src:

```
src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?> /imgs/whatever.png"
```

To get the `wp-content`'s URL, you can use [`content_url();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/content_url/).

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what i needed for the HTML side. Thanks for your help.

What do i do in the case of  CSS file

Comment: You're welcome! WordPress's main CSS file is located at the root of theme's folder, so you should create your links relatively to that folder. For example, you can use `../imgs/whatever.jpg` in your CSS file to point to `wp-content/imgs/whatever.jpg`. The `../` goes back once, and then navigates to `imgs/`

Comment: Thank you v much, and can this be repeated as needed? ../../../imgs for example?

Comment: Yes for sure. But It's not recommended to store ANY file outside your theme or upload directory, unless there is a very strong reason to.